# Can there be a compound which stops the pesticide from entering into the fruit or vegetable?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, biochemistry, solutions

Can there be a compound which stops the pesticide from entering into the fruit or vegetable? For example, a solution which is sprayed before pesticides and somehow blocks pesticides from entering into the fruit?

Comment: You mean a substance which itself stays completely on the surface, does not get washed off and pollutes the surroundings, is totally harmless to birds and insects, and completely decays into water and carbon dioxide within a few weeks?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the qualities @Karl stated (harmless, edible, overspray decomposes, etc.), such a coating would also need *to stretch as the produce grows*. Such a protective covering might even obviate the need for pesticides, if it were to be created.

That said, [there *are* edible wax and protein coatings to preserve produce](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fde8/fe9ac87496f50c1def579bc90d06bf292cc1.pdf) *after it's picked*. Unfortunately, these are applied *after* pesticides may have been sprayed on the food, so one hopes that the produce is washed *before* spraying seals in toxins.